# segmentation fault when using gcc 13.0 built directly from source

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently I downloaded and built the latest gcc 13.0 from source on WSL(Ubuntu) successfully in $HOME directory. Since my system already has gcc version 9 by default I decided against modifying it but rather use 'alias' and use the gcc13.
Now, the program seems to compile fine without any errors but when I run the code it throws a Segmentation fault(core dumped) error.

I later realized that since it's compiling fine there's got to be some problem with the linker so I recompiled with '-g -O0' flag and decided to check it with gdb.

Now, in gdb below is the error which I've been returned:

> > 0x00007fffff6f3f57 in std::ostream::operator<<(int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

So, with the above info one can deduce that the linker is using the object code from the default gcc 9 installation located at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu instead of the gcc 13 version.

Now, I'm stuck and have got no idea how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution here.
The problem is that the libraries which are being used by the linker belongs to the default installation of gcc i.e gcc-9 so the missing piece is that $LD_LIBRARY_PATH has to be set with the location of the libraries belonging to gcc13.
The following commands are the solution to the issue:

> echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/vivek/gcc13/lib64:/home/vivek/gcc13/lib32:/home/vivek/gcc13/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' >> ~/.bashrc

Now, the every C and C++ code is not just compiling but also running successfully.